# Java find whether the string characters are in given range

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am new to java and encoding and hence this question.

I basically have a text file, which contains the set of valid charater represented in hexademical values.
Example:
   0x2000-0x4002,0x5002-0x5F00

Now I have another file which contains the string.
Example:
    I am trying to use this file.

My problem is to check whether each of the character of the second file is valid and in the range described by the above file.

So this is what I am doing:

```
public class Test
{
   //This is a function used to build the ranges.
   public void build range() {}

   //This function will test whether the string str is in given range.
   public bool check range(String str)
   {
      int codePointCount = str.codePointCount(0, str.length());
      for( in ti =0; i< codePointCount; i++)
      {
          int value = str.codePointAt(i);
          if( value >= 2000 && value <= 4002 )
             continue;
          if( value >= 5002 && value <= 5F00 )
             continue;
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   } 
}
```

Please let me know whether this code is correct or I am missing something with respect to encoding.

Comment: is it even compiling properly? I doubt!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use regex, this is the idea

```
    boolean ok = !str.matches(".*[^\u2000-\u4002\u5002-\u5F00].*");
```

Answer (score 0):

First a small correction:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); )
  {
      int value = str.codePointAt(i);
      i += Character.charCount(value);
      if( value >= 0x2000 && value <= 0x4002 )
         continue;
      if( value >= 0x5002 && value <= 0x5F00 )
         continue;
      return false;
  }
```

But the answer of @EvgeniyDororfeev is best, in terms of length/readability.